# Can not connect to device using Flutter_bluetooth_serial package

Tags: java, android, flutter

However I receive that error

> D/FlutterBluePlugin( 3903): Connecting to 74:DF:BF:9B:46:2E (id: 2)
> I/BluetoothAdapter( 3903): cancelDiscovery I/BluetoothAdapter( 3903):
> cancelDiscovery = false D/BluetoothUtils( 3903):
> isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null I/BluetoothSocket(
> 3903): connect() for device 74DFBF called by pid: 3903
> W/BluetoothAdapter( 3903): getBluetoothService() called with no
> BluetoothManagerCallback I/flutter ( 3903):
> PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or
> timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might
> closed or timeout, read ret: -1 I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:970)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:984)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:536)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:57)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:64)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.lambda$onMethodCall$0$FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin(FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.java:880)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.-$$Lambda$FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$IghJwXXwUz_TFyaj49DgLpHhUY4.run(Unknown
> Source:10) I/flutter ( 3903):     at
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
> I/flutter ( 3903):    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoo

here is my code for connection

```
Future<bool> connect(String address) async {
    BluetoothConnection _bluetoothConnection;
    try {
      _bluetoothConnection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);
      return _bluetoothConnection.isConnected ? true : false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?